# I can't overwrite modules without export default

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, es6-modules

When I have the following scenario:

**Scenario 1:**

module.mjs:

```
const myAwesomeFunction = () => 42

export default {
  myAwesomeFunction
}
```

index.mjs:

```
import myModule from './module.mjs'

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(myModule, 'myAwesomeFunction'))

/* Returns

{
  value: [Function: myAwesomeFunction],
  writable: true,
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: true
}
*/

myModule.myAwesomeFunction = () => 84
console.log(myModule.myAwesomeFunction()) // prints 84
```

I can overwrite the `myAwesomeFunction` from my module to a custom function I made after, which is useful for testing purposes, I can use `spyOn` from Jasmine to mock that method before it gets used by another module

But when I have the following scenario:

**Scenario 2**

module.mjs

```
const myAwesomeFunction = () => 42

export {
  myAwesomeFunction
}
```

index.mjs

```
import * as myModule from './module.mjs'

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(myModule, 'myAwesomeFunction'))

/* Returns

{
  value: [Function: myAwesomeFunction],
  writable: true,
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: false <- That's a issue
}
*/

myModule.myAwesomeFunction = () => 84
console.log(myModule.myAwesomeFunction())

/* I get:

TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'myAwesomeFunction' of object '[object Module]'
    at file:///private/tmp/stackoverflow/index.mjs:15:28
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:195:25)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:337:24)
    at async loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:88:5)
    at async handleMainPromise (node:internal/modules/run_main:61:12)
*/
```

So, I can't stub methods coming from modules that don't have an `export default`. Like the ZX module that I've been using in a project. I tried using `const myModule = await import('module.mjs')`, but it doesn't work too.

For some reason, modules with `export default` are configurable, but without they are not.

Is there any workaround I can do to get these modules that match the second scenario configurable? My main use case is to get the `spyOn` from Jasmine able to mutate the original object, as it tries to do.